# Add events to Google Calendar via FullCalendar with Javascript

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I've used the instructions to set up Google Calendar as seen here — https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google-calendar — and it displays my events just fine.

I'm using the exact HTML demo for the external draggable events as seen here — https://fullcalendar.io/docs/external-dragging-demo

My confusion is why the events I update in FullCalendar don't update in Google Calendar. I presume gcal.js doesn't handle two-way synchronization?

If not, what can I do to 'CRUD' the events in FullCalendar over to Google Calendar?

Similar questions (which should be way more common) are very outdated or simply have no answer. Please help!

Thank you.

Comment: No, gcal.js doesn't do two-way. It only works because you made your calendar public - and the public data is read-only. If you want to be able to save events back to the calendar you'd need to use the full-blown Calendar API and have the user log in to google and approve your app etc. The you'd have to hook into fullCalendar's events (e.g. handle the event when the user finishes dragging) and write some code to make an ajax call to Google API at that time to update the event. Or use some server-side code in your own appllication as an intermediary.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/calendar/ has the API docs, guidance and some samples including JavaScript ones.

Comment: Thank you for all of that. It's much appreciated!